# Upload image to imgur failed because of cors

Tags: javascript, cors, imgur

I'm trying to upload an image to imgur with js (browser) and get a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

But preflight request contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header:
[image]

The request itself:
[image]

What I'm missing? this is because `access-control-allow-credentials` set to `true`?

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows `access-control-allow-origin: *` but the error says it's not there. I suspect the error is referring to a different request.

Comment: Thanks,  I added also a screenshot of the request itself. maybe I don't understand something with the CORS workflow.

Comment: The request screenshot doesn't seem to include the response headers?

Comment: The browser blocks the response because of the CORS policy.

Comment: Since the preflight request succeeded with CORS headers, the browser should send the POST request. If the POST response doesn't have CORS headers, the browser disallows JavaScript from accessing the response. It should still show in the devtools though. What if you run the same request outside a browser? Maybe in Postman. Do you see CORS headers there?

Comment: Those are the response headers of the POST request in Postman: https://i.imgur.com/aJeuA6C.png

Comment: Sorry, not sure why it isn't working. I think imgur needs to respond with CORS headers, but I don't see any other questions like this. Imgur links to an official example in their API docs, maybe try that and see if it works.

Comment: https://apidocs.imgur.com/#authorization-and-oauth checkout the auth in docs for it

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I don't understand how this link solves my problem. the request is correct, it works via postman

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was with their API Docs :\
The URL is: `https://api.imgur.com/3/image` and not `https://api.imgur.com/3/upload` as said here: https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139

Answer (score 0):

according to [doc](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139) `https://api.imgur.com/3/upload` doesnt have necessary
header ,

but on the right side ,the curl example use `https://api.imgur.com/3/image` has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

and somehow they will check your referer, which means if you are in develop mode like webpack dev mode use `localhost:8000` it will always return 429 `too many request`  exception